# How to prevent identical labels creating duplicate checkboxes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

The issue is the repeating of checkboxes. This is a snippet of the code in question.

```
<div class="row">
    <label data-ng-repeat="x in projects">
        <input
        type="checkbox"
        data-ng-true-value="{{x.b}}"
        data-ng-false-value=''
        ng-model="quer[queryBy]" />
        {{x.b}}
    </label>
</div>
```

This does what I want in producing checkboxes according to the repeated data to filter a table but the data in the label on occasion holds the same information in 'b'. How do I make it so I get only a single checkbox for a single common input.

Some context. This would create two checkboxes labelled '123', I only want one.

```
$scope.projects = [
  {
    a : "G",
    b : "123",
    c : "S1",

     {
    a : "R",
    b : "456",
    c : "S2",
  },
     {
    a : "G",
    b : "123",
    c : "S3",
  },
];
```

Comment: Group by `b`, so write a function loops through grouping by that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this angular extension: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Then adjust your ng-repeat as following:

```
 <label ng-repeat="x in projects | unique:'b'">
```

Comment: Can you provide some context as to why you think that will work.  That way future users will be able to understand this solution better.

Comment: Angular-filter extension provides pretty nice possibilities how to filter your collections. By using "unique" you can list only unique records in your collection based on the property. This extension is really helpful because it contains bunch of other useful filters.